# Can a friend connect to my singleplayer world over the internet?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to play one of my Minecraft singleplayer worlds with a friend that's not at my house?

I understand how LAN servers work when your on the same internet connection. but how would I play a single player world with a friend not at my house?

Comment: You could possibly set up a virtual LAN using Hamachi. I'm on my phone at the moment but have a read of [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1453421-hamachi-vlan-and-minecraft/)

Comment: 'Single-player'?

Comment: @Mondrianaire - singleplayer worlds can be hosted locally (it wasn't always the case), however the name has stuck

Comment: Ha, how silly. Creative title, then!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

no it is not possible, you will have to set up your own proper server rather than a LAN server then give your friend the ip address. it is relatively simple to do. you will have to make a copy of your "single-player" world and paste it into the online server. however any changes made in the online server will not transfer to your private file, so if you try to play offline then you will not have all the changes made while online.